# How do I get a custom localized string in the front end?

Tags: localization, c1-cms

I'm having trouble accessing localizations, the value always appears in the default language.

I have two resource files in App_GlobalResources:

- Resource.resx contains a string with the name "Hello" and the value of "World".
- Resource.fr.resx contains a string with the name "Hello" and the value of "Monde"

In my Razor template:

```
<lang:string key="Resource, Resources.Resource.Hello" xmlns:lang="http://www.composite.net/ns/localization/1.0" />
```

"World" is always displayed, never "Monde", even when viewing the page in French.

---

In a vanilla asp.net website template, with the same resources, the following code within a Razor template displays "Monde"

```
String cultureInfo = "fr-CA";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureInfo);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureInfo);
Response.Write(ObjectInfo.Print(Resources.Resource.Hello));
```

However, within C1 it results in "World".

---

How should I be going about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `<lang:string` construct is mainly meant for XSLT templates and functions where you can't as easily fallback to calling c# code directly as in Razor.

Have you tried printing out the resource on your Razor template like this instead `@Resources.Resource.Hello` ?

Comment: Yes, same result my strings are printed in the "neutral" language.

Comment: So, when you say your page is in French, how precisely is this defined? Have you added mulitple languages under System > Languages?

Comment: Yes. When the page is rendered and you view /fr/ content coming from C1 is properly localized, however, content from the resource file is not.